# How to use 2 attributes in Validation Rule Class Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

How can I use two attributes in the Validation Rule of Laravel. This is my function where I have 2 variables `groupid` and `grouppassword`. Currently only `groupid` is taken.

```
public function groupPasswordValidationReal(Request $request){
    $groupid = $request->input('groupid');
    $grouppassword = $request->input('grouppassword');

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'groupid' => [new ValidRequest] //How to pass grouppassword in this function???
    ]);

    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Request is send!');
}
```

How can I pass both to my Validation Class? Here you can see the functions in the Validation Class.

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Group;

class ValidTest implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //$value is groupid
        $validPassword = Group::where([['idgroups', $value],['group_password', /*Here I need grouppassword*/]])->first();
        if($validPassword){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Wrong Password!';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add property and constructor to your **ValidTest class**. Pass the required value as an argument to the new object.

**ValidTest.php**

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use App\Group;

class ValidTest implements Rule
{
    /**
     * The group password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $groupPassword;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @param  \App\Source  $source
     * @param  string  $branch
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($groupPassword)
    {
        $this->groupPassword = $groupPassword;
    }
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        //$value is groupid
        //$this->groupPassword is group_password
        $validPassword = Group::where([['idgroups', $value],['group_password', $this->groupPassword]])->first();
        if($validPassword){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'Wrong Password!';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function groupPasswordValidationReal(Request $request){
    $groupid = $request->input('groupid');
    $grouppassword = $request->input('grouppassword');

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'groupid' => new ValidTest($grouppassword)
    ]);

    return redirect('home')->with('success', 'Request is send!');
}
```

**Source** : [custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-5](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/custom-validation-rules-in-laravel-5-5-c6cb250f65df)

**Note** : This is not a tested solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Rule constructor` like

```
class ValidUser implements Rule
{
    private $grouppassword;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($grouppassword)
    {
        $this->grouppassword = $grouppassword;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // $this->grouppassword
        // $groupid = $value
        // Do your logic...
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must something...';
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Route::post('/user', function (Request $request) {
    // Parameter validation
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'groupid' => 'required',
        'grouppassword' => ['required', new ValidUser($request->groupid), ]
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 422);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a closure there. So something like this:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), function() use ($groupid, $grouppassword) {
        $validPassword = Group::where([['idgroups', $value],['group_password', $grouppassword]])->first();
        if($validPassword){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
}
```

I haven't run it though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the validation from a Request class, you can access the extra value as e.g.

```
request()->validate([
    'groupid' => [new ValidTest(request()->input('grouppassword'))]
]);
```